# How to retrieve a user's public Instagram posts?

Tags: instagram-api

How would you go about retrieving a user's Instagram posts, for a public account?

I have tried `instagram.com/username/?__a=1`, but that does not work through cURL or Post requests - it is also against the terms of service I believe.

Another possible solution would be to use the **Instagram Basic Display API**, but unfortunately they are not accepting new accounts for the past year almost.

Is there a way to retrieve a user's past 9 (or so) Instagram posts?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right about it being against their Terms of Service, but it does appear to be possible.

You may just need the **-L** parameter so your curl follows redirects...

**Request:**

```
curl -L https://www.instagram.com/espn/?__a=1
```

---

**Response:**

```
{
   "logging_page_id":"profilePage_1320207",
   "show_suggested_profiles":true,
   "show_follow_dialog":false,
   "graphql":{
      "user":{
         "biography":"Click the link ⤵️",
         "blocked_by_viewer":false,
         "restricted_by_viewer":false,
         "country_block":false,
         "external_url":"https://linkin.bio/ig-espn",
         "external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Flinkin.bio%2Fig-espn&e=ATOJohcCMk3afG1YAhT_AfhEq7ce4wZCpcFsTnB0PII_VAchFDkGsw6xzG1JZl80GU2KJOcTe64DxHaZvSWgGmCTPUJ8--McX102&s=1",
         "edge_followed_by":{
            "count":18323832
         },
         "fbid":"17841401206210020",
         "followed_by_viewer":false,
         "edge_follow":{
            "count":466
         },
         "follows_viewer":false,
         "full_name":"ESPN",
         ...
```

The response is very large, but I can confirm the most recent 12 posts are returned.

Comment: Thanks, how would you go about using the `-L` parameter in PHP? It seems to return blank

Comment: I believe it's: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: I think they have good detection in place, it seems to display the Instagram Logo (with 'need to login' based information being returned. The response is not the same, as visiting the URL directly, or making a normal cURL request

Comment: In other words, it does not work when being requested from a web server, it seems